# Invalid Literal for int() with base 10: "

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

I have a string of data from an accelerometer (x, y, z) (looks like this in text file "XXX XXX XXX" and I am attempting to read it and convert to a line graph with three subplots of data.  I'm adapting some code from a friend to do this but I'm not sure where some of these errors are coming from.  Obviously beginner programmer.  Help much appreciated.

Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10

```
import os
import numpy as npy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
global y0,y1,y2
increment_size = 8000
datasample_size = 16000

from os.path import join
filepath = "C:\\Users\\Riley\\Documents\\Programming\\"
infile = join(filepath, 'data.txt')
infile = open(infile,"r")
singleline = infile.readline()
asciidata = singleline.split()
asciidata[0]=asciidata[0][3:]  
y0=[int(asciidata[0])]
y1=[int(asciidata[1])]
y2=[int(asciidata[2])]

count = 0
for singleline in infile:
    count += 1
    if (count % 10000) == 0:
        print(count) 
    asciidata = singleline.split()
    y0.append(int(asciidata[0]))
    y1.append(int(asciidata[1]))
    y2.append(int(asciidata[2]))
infile.close()
totaldata=count-1
print(totaldata)

low = 0
high = datasample_size


while low < totaldata:

    t = npy.arange(low,high)

    plt.subplot(311)
    plt.ylim(-2000,2000)
    plt.plot(t,y0[low:high])

    plt.subplot(312)
    plt.ylim(-2000,2000)
    plt.plot(t,y1[low:high])

    plt.subplot(313)
    plt.ylim(-2000,2000)
    plt.plot(t,y2[low:high])

    outfilename = filepath + 'Plots/' + shortfilename + '_' + str(low) + '.png'
    plt.savefig(outfilename)

    outfilename2 = filepath + 'Datasegments/' + shortfilename + '_' + str(low) + '.txt'
    outfile = open(outfilename2,"w")
    for j in range(low,high):
        outfile.write(str(y0[j])+'\t'+str(y1[j])+'\t'+str(y2[j])+'\n')

#    print(low),

    plt.show()


    low = low + increment_size
    high = high + increment_size
    if high > totaldata:
        high = totaldata

#    if low > 10000:
#        break

# plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you may be trying to parse a `float()` with `int()`.

If you are needing to take care of empty values, try `int(s or 0)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a numpy function that does almost all of this for you.  It's hard for me to test it without knowing the format of your data file (it would help if you pasted in the first few lines of `'data.txt'`)

```
from os import path

import numpy as npy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

increment_size  =  8000
datasample_size = 16000

filepath = "C:\\Users\\Riley\\Documents\\Programming\\"
infile = path.join(filepath, 'data.txt')

# This line replaces all the file reading lines:
y0, y1, y2 = npy.genfromtxt(infile, unpack=True)

totaldata = len(y0)
print(totaldata)

low = 0
high = datasample_size

while low < totaldata:
    ...
```

Possibly the plotting could be done more simply too, but I'm not sure I understand why you are plotting it section by section.